# How may I count number of rasters in a list of raster stack

Tags: r, count

I have a `list` of `raster stacks` that each raster stack contains unequal number of rasters. How can I sum up number of rasters in my list? I have tried `length()` but this only returns  number of stacks in my list!
**example data:**

```
library(raster)

#reproducible example
set.seed(987)

#our list of rasters
r.lst <- as.list(1:3)

# setting up list pf raster stacks
r1 <- raster(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, res = 0.5, xmn = -1.5, xmx = 1.5, ymn = -1.5, ymx = 1.5, vals = runif(36, 1, 5))
r.lst[[1]] <- stack(lapply(1:7, function(i) setValues(r1,runif(ncell(r1)))))
r.lst[[2]] <- stack(lapply(1:3, function(i) setValues(r1,runif(ncell(r1)))))
r.lst[[3]] <- stack(lapply(1:2, function(i) setValues(r1,runif(ncell(r1)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is as below:

```
# count sum rasters
n <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(r.lst, nlayers))
n
#[1] 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nlayers` to get the number of layers (rasters) in a stack and `lapply` to apply that function on every element of your list:

```
lapply(my.list.of.rasterstacks, nlayers)
```

To sum them all up:

```
sum(unlist(lapply(my.list.of.rasterstacks, nlayers)))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
sum(sapply(r.lst, nlayers))
# [1] 12
```

or

```
sum(sapply(r.lst, dim)[3, ])
# [1] 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Without minimal data it's hard to answer

**EDIT**

With the example data, @Where's my towel has the correct answer

`sum(unlist(lapply(r.lst, nlayers)))`

Consider taking a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a good reproducible example for future questions.

Comment: This give me an error. For example data it is: 3 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you for including the example.

Comment: Thank @RomainB. I thought this really does not need example data as it was a straightforward question. But I have now much better solutions.